# Open non-compositional compound nouns

Tags: meaning, compounds, compound-words

Closely related to [my other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288205/compound-noun-with-completely-different-meaning), I am searching for an [open/spaced compound noun](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-compound.htm) for which the following properties hold:

- Its constituents have a well-known association. Such as "honey" and [**this picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GozvH.jpg)
- The meaning (and association) of the compound is unrelated to the associations (and meanings) of its constituents. Or in other words: the open compound noun is not obvious given the two individual words (seems considerably harder than finding closed compound nouns).
- The actual origin of the compound noun is irrelevant: it's about the general association that we have when looking at the words *individually*. Looking at "honey" individually, we think of honey. Looking at "moon" individually, we think of the moon. So "honeymoon" is the sort of compound noun of which the meaning is different from its constituents (too bad its not open).
- The compound is open/spaced, such as **tennis shoe**

Note that "*tennis shoe*" is an example of exactly *the opposite* of what I'm looking for. Tennis has a certain association. Shoe has a certain association. So the meaning of "tennis shoe" is obvious.

---

<sub>Nota bene: even though my question is closely related to my other question, the answers to my other question were mostly closed compound nouns. This question specifically targets open compound nouns, so it is different both from my previous questions and it needs (satisfactory) answers that were not given in the other question.</sub>

Comment: There's bound to be some association, even if only historical. Is _Denver boot_ an example of what you want?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's about the immediate and individual association, not about the origin of the compound noun. *Denver boot* is a perfect candidate indeed!

Comment: _Red herring_ is another, then. I've seen _hot dog_ classified as an NCC, though I'm not sure I agree. It could be a PCC (partially compositional compound).  Look up "non-compositional" + compounds

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Finally someone knows the actual name for it! I will edit my question. Why don't you post your suggestions as an answer below?

Comment: But how far removed does the literal meaning have to be? For instance, *blue chip* originally referred to gambling tokens that were literally colored blue, but few people who invest in *blue chips* nowadays would make that connection. If it's not a stock, it's a snack made from [blue corn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_corn). Similarly, the *Jerusalem artichoke* certainly has nothing to do with Jerusalem, and it is the root that is eaten and not the flowers as with a regular artichoke. The foliage is very vaguely similar, but consumers would not know how the foliage of either looks.

Comment: We have Voltaire's testimony that "Holy Roman Empire" is an example.

Comment: @choster Both are worthy candidates. Ambiguity, however, is discouraged. A perfect candidate compound noun would have a single strong association for each of the three meanings. Also, simple, frequently used words are often better examples than exotic words due to their well-known associations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

- [wet blanket](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=wet%20blanket)
- [white elephant](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=white%20elephant)
- [Dutch uncle](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=dutch%20uncle&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=0)
- [green thumb](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=green%20thumb&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=00) and its opposite, [black thumb](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=black%20thumb)
- [red tape](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=red%20tape&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=0)

Answer (score 4):

One of the most famous of misnomers is the *English horn* / *cor anglais*.

English horns are not English; they come from what is now largely Poland. 'The instrument originated in Silesia about 1720' {[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cor_anglais)}.

And they aren’t horns, but woodwind instruments related to the oboe.

*Red herring* and *Denver boot* are other examples. I've seen *hot dog* classified as an NCC (a non-compositional compound), though I'm not sure I agree. It could be a PCC (partially compositional compound).

Answer (score 2):

***po boy*** is neither poor nor a boy, it is a sandwich

Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Po%27_boy) : "A po' boy (also po-boy, **po boy**, or poor boy) is a traditional submarine sandwich from Louisiana" (Emphasis added)

po is dialect for poor.

Also, ***bush baby*** is neither a bush nor a baby -- It is a small primate, related to the lemur.  (Note that there are baby bush babies, juvenile bush babies, adult bush babies, and, if kept as pets, even old bush babies.)

From  *Duke Lemur Center, Thick Tailed Bush Baby*: "...Bush babies, or galagos, are small, nocturnal primates which range in size from cat-sized to mouse-sized. They are found in the forests and woodlands of Africa south of the Sahara."   http://lemur.duke.edu/discover/meet-the-lemurs/thick-tailed-bush-baby/#sthash.E8d2KNwS.dpuf